# NuXMV use of Real numbers

Tags: model-checking, nuxmv

I am using **nuXmv** on a work that I am developing, and I am having troubles using Reals.

Suppose I have the program:

```
MODULE main

VAR
  t : Real;
  r : 0..5000;

ASSIGN
  init(t):=0;
  init(r):=0;

TRANS
    case
      r>=500 :next(r)=0 & next(t)=0 & r<600;
      r<500 : next(t)-t>0 -> next(r)=r+t & next(r)<600;
    esac;

SPEC
    AG r<=600
```

The property on this example that I am trying to prove is that r is always less or equal to 600.
Note that this is just an illustrative example with no concrete meaning.

Now on command line I type

```
$ nuXmv <fileName>
```

in order to run the program and check if the property is achieved, but this message appears

> "In this version of nuXmv, batch mode is not available with models containing infinite domain variables."

So the problem that I have identified is the use of `Real` on variable `t`.
Is there a way to specify a range of Real values like the one I have used on variable `r` (which is of type Integer)?
I know that if this exists that could solve the problem, if not, how can I use Reals in my program?

Thank you in advance for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The complete error message does tell you how to get around this issue:

> In this version of nuXmv, batch mode is not available with models
>   containing infinite domain variables.
>
> You can enter **interactive mode** calling:
>
> ```
> ./nuXmv -int file_name.smv
> ```
>
> Alternatively, you can write the commands you want to execute in a file and then call:
>
> ```
> ./nuXmv -source <command-file> file_name.smv
> ```

---

*AFAIK*, to deal with an **infinite domain variables**, you are expected to take advantage of the model checking techniques based on the **[MathSAT 5](http://mathsat.fbk.eu/)** SMT Solver. This means that you should focus on commands which have `msat` as prefix or suffix in their name when you [look at the manual](https://es.fbk.eu/tools/nuxmv/downloads/nuxmv-user-manual.pdf).

Notice that there is no `msat_` command for doing **CTL Model Checking** within **[nuXmv](https://nuxmv.fbk.eu/)**, though **LTL and Invariant Model Checking** are available, so you should change your property

```
SPEC AG r <= 600
```

into

```
LTLSPEC G r <= 600
```

You can then verify the model as follows:

```
     ~$ nuXmv -int
nuXmv > reset ;
nuXmv > read_model -i file_name.smv ;
nuXmv > go_msat ;
nuXmv > msat_check_ltlspec_bmc
```

---

You ask:

> Is there a way to specify a range of Real values like the one I have used on variable `r` (which is of type Integer) ?

No, `0.0..500.0` is illegal.

You have the following options

```
rv : real ;      -- can represent any rational value, infinite domain
iv : integer ;   -- can represent any integer value, infinite domain
fv : LB..UB ;    -- can represent any integer value in the domain [LB, UB]
sv : {0, 2, 4} ; -- can represent either 0, 2 or 4.
```

If you want to add range constraints to a **real**/**integer** variable, you can use **INVAR**:

```
INVAR 0.0 <= rv & rv <= 500.0 ;
```

Comment: Excellent explanation on how it works. I am speechless actually on how perfect the answer was.